# jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

Tags: keystore

While I was executing my certsign.sh script in my workarea ,I got  the below  error 
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

The contents of the certsign.sh is this one :-

```
echo "Signing Client.jar"
jarsigner -keystore GeminiDD_KS -storepass GeminiDD Client.jar GeminiDD
echo "Client.jar Signed... Verificiation in progress"
jarsigner -verify Client.jar
```

But when I am executing the same script in some other location it is not showing error.

Comment: Same issue here.  Import went fine, it recognizes/displays it properly with keytool -list, but the jarsigner pukes on it.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

If the behaviour is different on different systems it may depend on the Java version opr vendor. Which version of java are you using on your workstation (official Oracle JDK, OpenJDK...)?

You can also force the use of Java Keystore format in your signing script:

> jarsigner -keystore GeminiDD_KS -storetype JKS -storepass GeminiDD Client.jar GeminiDD